# LibGDX: How to make an object falls with random speed

Tags: java, libgdx, android

I'm trying to make an object (ball) fall into position Y and when the ball collides with the base. The sprite changes and along with the change I want the speed of the fall to change according to the sprite

```
public void create () {
    circleBall = new Circle();
    rectangleBase = new Rectangle();
    ball = new Texture("ball.png"); 
}

public void render () {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    fallBall();
    rand();
    spriteBatch.end();
}

void fallBall(){
    fallSpeed++;
    if(posYBall > 0){
        posYBall -= fallSpeed * 2 / 2;
    }
}

void rand(){
    int rand1 = random.nextInt(15 - 1) + 1;
    int rand2 = random.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
    int rand3 = random.nextInt((55 - 35) + 1) + 35;
    collisionBallBase(rand1, rand2, rand3);
}

void collisionBallBase(int rand1, int rand2, int rand3){
    if(Intersector.overlaps(circleBall, rectangleBase)){
        if(rand1 <= 5){
            ball = new Texture("ball.png");
        }else if(rand1 <= 10){
            ball = new Texture("ballb.png");
        }else{
            ball = new Texture("ballc.png");
        }

        if(rand2 >= 5){
            ballDirection = 4;
        }else{
            ballDirection = -4;
        }
        fallSpeed = -rand3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just multiply fallSpeed with a variable that get's changed to some other random value every time your condition is met. You need to generate a random float that varies between, for example, 0.5 and 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the `rand` function in a render, you can call the function when your action happened.

If you want to have a ball with a random speed on creation time do it on the constructor.

If you want the ball to have a random speeds every time for each activity such a collision, set it in the 'on event' function.

If you really want to call a function in a render function then try something like this

```
boolean collided = false

somefunctionto
if(collided){
   set_random_speed_to_a_ball(..);
   collided = false;
}

render(){
   if(collisionhappend){
   collided = true;
}
```